# Sort rows of a dataframe in descending order of NaN counts

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to sort the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
         RHS  age  height  shoe_size  weight
0     weight  NaN     0.0        0.0     1.0
1  shoe_size  NaN     0.0        1.0     NaN
2  shoe_size  3.0     0.0        0.0     NaN
3     weight  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0
4        age  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0
```

in such a way that the rows with a greater number of NaNs columns are positioned first.
More precisely, in the above df, the row with index 1 (2 Nans) should come before ther row with index 0 (1 NaN).

What I do now is:

```
df.sort_values(by=['age', 'height', 'shoe_size', 'weight'], na_position="first")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `df.sort_values` and `loc` based accessing.

```
df = df.iloc[df.isnull().sum(1).sort_values(ascending=0).index]
print(df)

         RHS  age  height  shoe_size  weight
1  shoe_size  NaN     0.0        1.0     NaN
2  shoe_size  3.0     0.0        0.0     NaN
0     weight  NaN     0.0        0.0     1.0
4        age  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0
3     weight  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0
```

`df.isnull().sum(1)` counts the `NaN`s and the rows are accessed based on this sorted count.

---

@ayhan offered a [nice little improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909776/sort-rows-of-a-dataframe-in-descending-order-of-nan-counts/45909850?noredirect=1#comment78778587_45909850) to the solution above, involving `pd.Series.argsort`:

```
df = df.iloc[df.isnull().sum(axis=1).mul(-1).argsort()]
print(df)

         RHS  age  height  shoe_size  weight 
1  shoe_size  NaN     0.0        1.0     NaN           
0     weight  NaN     0.0        0.0     1.0           
2  shoe_size  3.0     0.0        0.0     NaN           
3     weight  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0           
4        age  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0
```

Comment: Sorting and getting the index can be done in one operation with argsort. `df.iloc[np.argsort(-df.isnull().sum(axis=1))]` It is also defined on pd.Series as a method. `df.iloc[df.isnull().sum(axis=1).mul(-1).argsort()]` It is very similar so I thought I would just leave it here instead of posting an answer.

Comment: @ayhan Ooh, nice! Added that to my answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: Sure. That's why I commented. :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ or maybe `df.iloc[df.stack().groupby(level=0).count().sort_values().index]` :)

Comment: Hi, I'm new to python - the above code worked for me but I was just wondering if you could break down what each function does. I would like to understand the logic rather than copying and editing the code ```df.iloc[df.isnull().sum(1).sort_values(ascending=0).index]```. My understanding is df.iloc gets the row number, df.isnull() is self explanatory, sum(1) gets the sum of df.isnull() for each row, sort_values(ascending=0) sorts number of null in ascending order, but what does the function .index do?

Comment: @cms72 the last step is to extract the sorted indices so they can be passed to iloc to reorder the original DataFrame and get the expected result.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner that will do it:

```
df.assign(Count_NA = lambda x: x.isnull().sum(axis=1)).sort_values('Count_NA', ascending=False).drop('Count_NA', axis=1)
#          RHS  age  height  shoe_size  weight
# 1  shoe_size  NaN     0.0        1.0     NaN
# 0     weight  NaN     0.0        0.0     1.0
# 2  shoe_size  3.0     0.0        0.0     NaN
# 3     weight  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0
# 4        age  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0
```

This works by assigning a temporary column ("Count_NA") to count the NAs in each row, sorting on that column, and then dropping it, all in the same expression.

Comment: Not much of a one liner if it uses lambda and has to create and drop temp columns...

Comment: Agreed, it's a bit hackey. Using `iloc` is better :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a column of the number of null values, sort by that column, then drop the column.  It's up to you if you want to use `.reset_index(drop=True)` to reset the row count.

```
df['null_count'] = df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
df.sort_values('null_count', ascending=False).drop('null_count', axis=1)

# returns
         RHS  age  height  shoe_size  weight
1  shoe_size  NaN     0.0        1.0     NaN
0     weight  NaN     0.0        0.0     1.0
2  shoe_size  3.0     0.0        0.0     NaN
3     weight  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0
4        age  3.0     0.0        0.0     1.0
```