# How to sort a pandas dataframe by the length of its rows

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe i want to sort by the length of its rows. The dataframe looks like this: [a dataset loaded into a dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dF91.png). The dataframe consists of ca. 7000 transactions. I want to sort so that the transactions that include the most items are at the top.

Comment: Please add the DataFrame in way that can be copied into a Python editor

Comment: This might be relevant to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909776/sort-rows-of-a-dataframe-in-descending-order-of-nan-counts

Comment: Shouldn’t the rows all have the same length, or am I missing something?

Comment: please check my answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
df.loc[pd.isna(df).sum(axis=1).sort_values(axis=0).index]
```

In short what it does:
`pd.isna()` will return `true/false` dataframe of the same shape as your original one with `True` if respective cell is `NaN` in the original dataframes.
Next you sum it up per row (`.sum(axis=1)`), which will return number of `NaN` in given row, for each row. Then I sort it and return only sorted indexes, which then I provide to `.loc[]` method to return rows in the requested order.

Comment: really although this is typically done with sum + isna this is simplified with count

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) with `axis = 1` 
to count the number of non-null elements / NaN by rows, then order this series based on their values 
and use its index to reindex the dataframe with [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df.reindex(index=df.count(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index)
```

---

**Here is an example**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,np.nan],'col2':[np.nan,4,np.nan],'col3':[1,2,3]})
print(df)
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0   NaN     1
1   2.0   4.0     2
2   NaN   NaN     3

df=df.reindex(index=df.count(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).index).
print(df)

   col1  col2  col3
1   2.0   4.0     2
0   1.0   NaN     1
2   NaN   NaN     3
```